# How to add sliding image to site.com

Tags: site.com, static-resources, images

I am designing a site.com in this site i am trying to get 3 image from static resource and need to slide using jQuery. Is this possible? If there is any way to get the scenario done please guide me.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" >
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.box_skitter_large').skitter({
            theme: 'clean',
            numbers_align: 'center',
            progressbar: true, 
            dots: true, 
            preview: true
        });
        progress(80, $('#progressBar'));
        progress(30, $('#progressBar1'));
        progress(46, $('#progressBar3'));
        progress(100, $('#progressBar4'));


            $('#ticker2').rssfeed('{!homepgSettingRSSF[0].Feed_url__c }',{}, function(e) {
                $(e).find('div.rssBody').vTicker({ showItems: 1, height: 130});
            });




    });
    function progress(percent, $element) {
        var progressBarWidth = percent * $element.width() / 100;
        $element.find('div').animate({ width: progressBarWidth }, 500).html(percent + "%&nbsp;");
    }



    </script>

<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.imageSlider, 'thiagosf-SkitterSlideshow-9ddbfc3/js/jquery-1.6.3.min.js')}"/>
```

Comment: I don't see any reason for it to not to work. Is there certain grey area that you believe might cause an issue? If yes, update that as a concern.

Comment: but how to add 3 images.. i am able to add 1 image and able to apply css and script to 1 image only. i need get slide 1 by 1

Comment: Which jQuery plugin are you using?

Comment: i have done sliding image in my application now i want in my code. I have updated my question

Answer (score 1):

GO with this link download and use it in your site.com home page

[Jquery Cycle](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/)